# How to delete a space between QLabel and QLineEdit

Tags: qt

I want to reduce space between label and QLineEdit (QLabel is above QLineEdit). How can I achieve it? In the code I'm creating items, that I later put in some layouts.

```
QLabel* lgamma = new QLabel("Gamma");
gamma = new QLineEdit();
QLabel* lmin_linie = new QLabel(QString::fromUtf8("Min. il. zmian linii"));
min_lin = new QLineEdit();
// ...
QLabel* lmax_kursy = new QLabel(QString::fromUtf8("Max zm. il. kursów"));
max_kursy = new QLineEdit();
QGridLayout *lay = new QGridLayout(this);
QVBoxLayout *box1 = new QVBoxLayout();
QVBoxLayout *box2 = new QVBoxLayout();
// ...
QVBoxLayout *box12 = new QVBoxLayout();
box1->addWidget(lmin_linie);
box1->addWidget(min_lin);
box2->addWidget(lmax_lin);
box2->addWidget(max_lin);
// ...
box12->addWidget(literacje);
box12->addWidget(iteracje);
verticalColumn1->addLayout(box1);
verticalColumn1->addLayout(box2);
// ...
verticalColumn3->addLayout(box12);

start = new QPushButton("Start", this);
QHBoxLayout *corn = new QHBoxLayout();
corn->addLayout(verticalColumn1);
corn->addLayout(verticalColumn2);
corn->addLayout(verticalColumn3);
QVBoxLayout *rup = new QVBoxLayout();
rup->addLayout(corn);
rup->addWidget(start);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add a spacer to your layout.

```
QSpacerItem *spacer = new QSpacerItem(1, 50, QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
box1.addItem(spacer);
```

Adapt the args or [QSpacerItem](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qspaceritem.html) for your needs, for examle `QSizePolicy::Preferred` could be better than `QSizePolicy::Expanding`, and reduce the preferred height (second argument).
Why don't you use the easy way to do that GUI with Qt designer ?

Comment: @Chris Adding spacer at the top or the bottom will compress all other items in the layout instead of letting them spread out evenly and take the whole space.

Comment: Ah I see what you're doing, I wasn't paying close enough attention to where you were putting the spacer.

Comment: Actually in my example, it could increase the size of the widget, depending on where you put spacers. But my example is just a way to compress space between elements and obviously, you have to change the parameters (for example with **Preferred** instead of **Expanding**, or better, use Qt designer (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set QLabel and QLineEdit border:

```
lmax_kursy->setStyleSheet("border-width:0px");
max_kursy->setStyleSheet("border-width:0px");
```

or set spacing in layout. First check what is a current value of spacing:

```
box1->spacing();
```

If it's 0, try to set negative value like -2:

```
box1->setSpacing(-2);       // or 0 or something else
```

Comment: That won't suffice without the addStretch() from the other answer.